# Finding all posts without tags in Django Postgres ArrayField

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Just like what my title says, I want to see all my posts without any tags. However none of the following ORM is working:

```
x = PostTagging.obejcts.filter(tags=[])
x = PostTagging.objects.filter(tags__len=0)
```

All I get as a return is:

```
<QuerySet []>
```

**Here is my model:**

```
class PostTagging(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my ORM for creating the blank tag:

```
PostTagging.objects.create(title='Fifth Post')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostTagging.objects.filter(tags__isnull=True)` is the best way